# Наложения картинок на php

Tags: gd, изображения, php

Мой код для наложения картинки

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("http://anton.biz.ua/vkapp1/img/ramka.png");

$is = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://cs309825.vk.me/v309825618/6ede/6OpXyfvCFeE.jpg");
imagecopy($im, $is, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($is), imagesy($is));

header ("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Но когда я запускаю скрипт то у меня выводит такое

[image: изображение]

Так где серое это прозрачный фон, а сверху 41 пиксель только загрузился, а нужно что бы
все полностью загружалось, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А кто его знает. Я попробовал с сохранением png в файл -- накладывает. Масштабы разные, картинка получается смешная -- небольшой квадрат в углу прямоугольника, но копирует...

Comment: Попробуйте поэкспериментировать с локальными файлами. Видимо скрипт не полностью загружает картинку, либо сервер не отдает картинку...

Comment: Ничего что по ссылке для рамки открывается далеко не картинка?

Answer (score 1):

[function.imagesavealpha](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagesavealpha.php)

Еще мне показалось, что попутаны местами изображения — нужно же, наверное, накладывать рамку на картинку?

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("http://anton.biz.ua/vkapp1/img/ramka.png");
imagealphablending($im, false);
imagesavealpha($im, true);

$is = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://cs309825.vk.me/v309825618/6ede/6OpXyfvCFeE.jpg");
imagealphablending($is, true);

imagecopy($is, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

header ("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($is);
imagedestroy($is);

die();
```

Comment: anton.biz.ua/vkapp1/load_img.php вот, не грузит

Comment: Как, не грузит? [Грузит же](http://bars.koding.com/trash/vkapp1.jpg)!